# Dynamic name space in Spring-ws

Tags: web-services

I want to load a dynamic namespace value in the endpoint of my spring-ws.
Please some one help me to do this.

Below given is my current code and is working fine.

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "AuthenticateRequest", namespace = "myurl")
@ResponsePayload
public AuthenticateResult Authenticate(@RequestPayload AuthenticateRequest authRequest) 
{
AuthenticateResult response = JAXB_OBJECT_FACTORY.createAuthenticateResult();

return response;
}
```

Here instead of the hard-coded namespace,  I want a dynamic value which is read from a properties file/XML.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: i had this same issue recently. i ended up creating a method for each of the needed namepsace.